# Is there any Python method to convert base64 encoded string to Image

Tags: python

I'm sending the file from PHP to python server which contains an Image Encoded String I am reading it in python and write the image in a folder. The `image.jpg` file appears in the folder but can't be displayed and the file created in the folder shows 0-byte file size.

```
import base64
import sys
file=sys.argv[1]
f=open(file)
base_64=f.read()
with open("image.jpg","wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.decodebytes(base_64))
```

Answer (score 0):

open file in 'rb' mode so it will write an img file

```
import base64
import sys
file=sys.argv[1]
f=open(file,"rb")
base_64=f.read()
with open("image.jpg","wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.decodebytes(base_64))
```